# Observer pattern liabilities: Why would observer change its subject?

Tags: design-patterns

While reading an articles on observer pattern, I came across below point listed under Liabilities of observer pattern

> Observer objects are totally independent and they have no knowledge on the existence of the fellow Observers. Therefore, **an Observer object can change the state of the Subject** (in the Update method) before even all the Observers are notified. This may result in state inconsistencies and the state change notifications will be lost.

1. Why would observer change subject? Isn't observers should be notified on change in subject rather that changing the subject by itself?

In case if it is possible

1. Pls let me know thro' an example
2. Also specify why not subject can restrict itself from allowing any observer to change it before earlier change is notified to all observers?

Answer (score 3):

Nowhere it is stated that an Observer can't itself change its Subject, although it is not recommended in most of the cases, due to the reasons above. However, technically it is possible, especially if the notification call includes the Subject itself as a parameter:

```
class MyObserver implements Observer<MySubject> {
  ...
  public void notify(MySubject theSubject) {
    ...
    theSubject.changeSomeProperty(newValue);
  }
  ...
}
```

As for how to prevent observers from changing the Subject while a notification cycle is going on, I see some options, but each of these introduces extra complexity, none of these is 100% guarantee, and some are more hassle than it's worth.

- pass only a read-only interface of Subject to Observers - this is the easiest to implement, with no side effects, however an evil Observer may still attempt to downcast Subject to access its modifier methods, and/or to access the full Subject via some other object(s)
- implement the public Subject as a read-only Adapter to the real Subject, and publish only the former - this prevents the downcasting trick, and may make it more difficult (but not impossible) for Observers to access the real Subject via some other object(s)
- "lock" the Subject for the time of the update by setting e.g. a flag, which is checked in each modifier method (and then e.g. throws an exception if the flag is on) - this prevents not only Observers but everyone from modifying the Subject during the critical time, which may or may not be desirable

Answer (score 1):

Although it is not recommended, there is nothing stopping the observers from changing the state of the observed object (usually, see const-correctness in C++ for counterexample).  Of course, the observed object might be able to jump though hoops to prevent/disallow this, but that is tedious.

If the state is changed before all other observers have visited the object, they will find a state different than what they were expecting (were notified of).

Answer (score 1):

If our subject is `S` and we have two observers registered; `A` and `B`, then:

If `A`'s `responseHandler()` contains code that would modify `S`, then it would change the state of `S` before `B` gets notified.

Code for handling specific ordering or other special conditions would belong in `S`'s `notifyObservers()` method, where you might flag `S` as non-modifiable or maybe prepare some specific order of nottification to update `S`.